# how reachs an object with getter setter from different package in java?

Tags: java, list, null, encapsulation, getter-setter

```
public class Class1 {
    List<Class3> allData = new ArrayList<Class3>();

    public void setAllData(List<Class3> allData) {
        this.allData = allData;
    }

    public List<Class3> getAllData() {
        return allData;
    }
}
```

I have a class which name is Class2 in different package but in the same project with Class1 . How I reach to "allData" from Class1 to use in Class2 ? With getter and setter ? Or any alternative way ?

Comment: What do you mean by reach? get ? or Set?

Answer (score 0):

> How I reach to "allData" from Class2? With getter and setter? Or any alternative way?

yes, you should use `public` getter/setter. The only alternative way is to use  reflection (or make `allData` public, which is not recommended too - brokes [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming))).

Your `allData` field is `package-private`, so you can't directly reach it from class `Class2` which is placed in another package

Comment: Is it impossible to reach an object from different package? Is there any alternative?

Comment: Just declare allData as public... As you're not specifying anything, default is package-private as @Cootri said

Comment: **public List<Class3> allData = new ArrayList<Class3>();**  ..Now how can I reach that?

Comment: yes, you can. But it is a bad OOP design - brokes encapsulation

Comment: Can you give me an idea? I am junior about writing java. How should I reach that object from different package? Can you write a sample code here?

Comment: why you don't want to use `getAllData` and `setAllData` methods? It is a common approach

Answer (score 0):

You can reach private fields with public getter and setter methods.

You have to make a public getter method in Class2. Then you can call that method in the other classes.

Answer (score 0):

From the other class you first have to instantiate an Class1 object.

`Class1 c1 = new Class1()`

Then you can access `allData` using the getters and setters.

`List<Class3> allData = c1.getAllData();`

```
List<Class3> newAllData = new ArrayList<Class3>();
c1.setAllData(newAllData);
```